# How to get rid off unused dll's in wix when upgrade is uninstalled

Tags: wix, upgrade

I have a code that has some changes from the previous version. During changes, some dll's were removed. I am using wix to create installer. So now, when I upgrade from old version to new version and when I uninstall the product, inside the product folder, I see those old dll's still present.

Logically, it is correct as old version has those files. When upgraded, new version replaces its new dll's. On uninstalling the product(new version here), those dll's are not a part of new version so they are not deleted.

How can I change my new version deployment code to resolve this upgrade issue?

Expected result: Uninstalling the upgraded version should delete all dll's from product folder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Bob Arnson: I don't want to do a major upgrade as I want the previous version to be not uninstalled but upgraded. So I came up with a fix for now using RemoveFile tag under those components that specifies those file ids to be deleted in case they are present.

```
<RemoveFile Id = "id_to_be_removed" On = "uninstall" Name = "dll_name"/>
```

Comment: You're going in the wrong direction here - this is not the way to do an upgrade. It sounds like you need to create a patch to update the existing installed app.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a major upgrade if you remove components. See [Changing the Product Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367850%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the list of things that cannot be done with minor upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not logical :) If you have a) really done a successful major upgrade and b) those Dlls were only in the older version and not in the newer upgrade you installed then they should not be there at all. The old product is no longer there if the upgrade was successful, and there is no old version to have those files - it's uninstalled by the upgrade. If you have two entries in Programs&Features then you didn't do a correct replacement upgrade and that older product is still installed. If you have only one entry in Programs&Features then there is most likely something wrong with your use of component ids. It really is all about those ids sometimes. For example, if you used the same component id in the upgrade for something else in the new upgrade then Windows Installer cannot ref count that id (associated with that older Dll) down to zero and remove the older DLL. Make sure the component ids for those older Dlls are not in the new upgrade. Apart from that, if you ever marked those Dlls as Permanent or SharedLegacy then they won't be uninstalled when the upgrade removes the older product.

Before deciding what to do you should figure out exactly what is going on. You cannot install the same ProductCode twice, so you are going into some kind of maintenance mode are you are NOT doing an upgrade and you have NOT installed a new product. If you want to actually do an upgrade then use the WiX majorupgrade element.

Comment: I don't think it to be a major upgrade as the product id is not changed. Am I correct? I checked the component id and it's not used in the new upgrade anywhere. I have only one entry in Programs&Features. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I think I can use custom action but I don't know yet the value of each property to add. Any suggestions will be great..

Comment: Read my updated answer. If the product id is the same and you just installed your new MSI then you have done nothing except a maintenance repair of the installed product. You have not installed a new product.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is not a major upgrade. Then back to the old problem: how can I remove those dll's not referred in new version?

Comment: As in my answer, if you do a proper major upgrade then simply don't include the Dlls in the new upgrade setup. A major upgrade uninstalls the old version and should be no different from a plain uninstall of that old product. If a plain uninstall doesn't leave Dlls behind but the upgrade does, then, again, read the first part of the answer.